# Deleting line breaks in a text file with a condition

Tags: c#

I have a text file. Some of the lines in it end with lf and some end with crlf. I only need to delete lfs and leave all crlfs.

Basically, my file looks like this

> Mary had a lf
>
> dog.crlf
>
> She liked her lf
>
> dog very much. crlf

I need it to be

> Mary had a dog.crlf
>
> She liked her dog very much.crlf

Now, I tried just deleting all lfs unconditionally, but then I couldn't figure out how to write it back into the text file. If I use File.WriteAllLines and put a string array into it, it automatically creates line breaks all over again. If I use File.WriteAllText, it just forms one single line.
So the question is - how do I take a text file like the first and make it look like the second? Thank you very much for your time.
BTW, I checked similar questions, but still have trouble figuring it out.

Comment: You can load the file up, and call a `Regex.Replace(filecontents, @"(?<!\r)\n", String.Empty);` ([see docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7f5w83z.aspx))

Comment: Filecontents represents a single string? If so, how do I write it back into the file and will it have the needed structure? Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're going to need to post how you are either reading the file or how you're generating the file. It's my understanding you're using the `File` object with a couple of methods, but I'd need to see more structure to make an accurate determination.

Comment: It works! I did string text = File.ReadAllText, than did what you said with that string and used File.WriteAllText("url", text);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regex with a negative look-behind and only replace the `\n` not preceded by a `\r`:

[DEMO](http://www.ideone.com/H3945)

```
var result = Regex.Replace(sampleFileContent, @"(?<!\r)\n", String.Empty);
```

The `(?<!` ... `)` is a [negative look-behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). It means that we only want to replace instances of `\n` when there isn't a `\r` directly behind it.

***Disclaimer:** This may or may not be as viable an option depending on the size of your file(s).  This is a good solution if you're not concerned with overhead or you're doing some quick fixes, but I'd look in to a more robust parser if the files are going to be huge.*

Comment: ur magic not working.. better try "\r|\n"

Answer (score 2):

This is an alternative to Brad Christie's answer, which doesn't use Regex.

```
String result = sampleFileContent.Replace("\r\n", "**newline**")
                                 .Replace("\n","")
                                 .Replace("**newline**","\r\n");
```

[Here's a demo.](http://www.ideone.com/sVIP2) Seems faster than the regex solution according to this site, but uses a bit more memory.

Answer (score 1):

Just tested it:

```
string file = File.ReadAllText("test.txt");
file = file.Replace("\r", "");
File.WriteAllText("test_replaced.txt", file);
```

Comment: Again, this, unconditionally, replaces **all** carriage returns. And even so the OP wants stranded line-feeds replaced, not carriage-returns. -- EDIT: or I'm wrong...